# C++/CLI Передача структуры в метод интерфейса

Tags: c++-cli

```
ref class CFoo
{
public:

    ref struct FooStructure
    {
        int i;
    };

    void Func(IFoo^ myI) {
        myI->Func(gcnew FooStructure());
    }
};

interface class IFoo
{
public:
    void Func(CFoo::FooStructure^ s);
};
```

Пишет следующее: `Function "IFoo::Func" cannot be called with the given argument list  argument types are: (CFoo::FooStructure ^)  object type is: IFoo ^`.

Эмм... Нельзя передавать структуры принадлежащие классам в методы интерфейса?

Comment: Структуры передаются по значению. Поэтому уберите в объявлении интерфейса знак `^`.

Comment: Ничего из этого не выйдет конечно же. У нас управляемый класс.

Comment: Проблема как бы в том, что структура объявлена в классе. Странно лишь то, что если объявить эту структуру в другом управляемом классе, то всё будет работать.

Comment: По идее же, какая разница?..

Comment: @D.Stark: Как вы объявили "якобы" управляемую структуру, нативной записью `c++`?

Comment: IFoo должен быть объявлен до CFoo::Func, чтобы это все взлетело.

Comment: Вот так дак не работает: https://pastebin.com/vifrwpwq

Comment: Точнее определен, а не объявлен. Т.е. полностью, со списком методов.

Comment: Так не работает всё равно: https://pastebin.com/FCy0xPaf `'CFoo': is not a class or namespace name    'IFoo::Func': function does not take 1 argument`

Comment: Как CFoo::FooStructure объявить до определения интерфейса? В этом же вроде дело...

Comment: Никак. Вы пытаетесь писать на С++ как на C#, но это не работает. Надо делать либо оба внутрь CFoo, либо оба снаружи.

Comment: Ну вот так я и думал. Ответ на вопрос значит: никак.